# Cambiar los valores de una matriz de booleans

Tags: java, eclipse, matrices, booleano

Debo hacer una matriz de F filas y C columnas con valores lógicos e inicializarla con true.

El problema lo tengo cuando me piden introducir un número M y cambiar M casillas de la matriz a false. En el caso de que M sea menor o igual a C debo comprobar que todavía queden M casillas con el valor true en una única fila e indicar cual es.

A continuación mostraré el código que tengo.

```
boolean[][] asientos = new boolean[F][C]; // matriz de valores logicos

        System.out.println("Los asientos del autobús son:");
        for (int i = 0; i < F; i++) {
            for(int j =0; j<C;j++) {
                asientos[i][j] = true;
                System.out.print(asientos[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println(); //imprime un salto de linea
        }

        do {
            System.out.println("\nIndique el número de billetes a comprar (entre 1 y " + ((F*C)-M)
                    + "). Introduzca 0 para finalizar el programa. ");
            d = TECLADO.nextInt();

            while (d < 0 || d > (F*C)-M) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Error el numero de asientos a comprar debe ser mayor o igual a 0 y menor o igual que el número de asientos libres ("
                                + ((F*C)-M) + ")");
                d = TECLADO.nextInt();
            }

            M = M + d;

            if (d != 0) {
                System.out.println("Se pueden comprar " + d + " asientos.");
                if (M == (F*C)) {
                    System.out.println("\nSe han ocupado todos los asientos.");
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < F; i++) { //aquí empiezo a tener el problema, por lo que el código estará mal
                        for(int j =0; j < C;j++) {
                            asientos[i][j] = false;
                            System.out.print(asientos[i][j]+" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (d != 0 && M != (F*C));
```

No sé si conseguí explicarme bien, pero cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que entiendo tu problema, pero mirando el código vi un par de cosas que considero incorrectas:

- Entiendo que tienes que comenzar la matriz con un numero M de asientos ocupados, eso deberías fijarlo antes de imprimir la matriz.
- Donde pones que el código esta mal, efectivamente es erroneo e incompleto, en los comentarios explico un poco más.

Te dejo aquí una propuesta de mejora:

```
    boolean[][] asientos = new boolean[F][C]; // matriz de valores logicos

    if (M > C) {
        System.out.println("Datos de entrada no validos. M debe ser menor que C");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("Los asientos del autobús son:");
    // Aqui saco una copia de M , para utilizarla en el bucle para fijar los 'false' iniciales de forma simple
    int Mcopy = M;
    for (int i = 0; i < F; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if (Mcopy != 0) {
                asientos[i][j] = false;
                Mcopy--;
            } else {
                asientos[i][j] = true;
            }
            System.out.print(asientos[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(); // imprime un salto de linea
    }

    do {
        System.out.println("\nIndique el número de billetes a comprar (entre 1 y " + ((F * C) - M)
                + "). Introduzca 0 para finalizar el programa. ");
        d = TECLADO.nextInt();

        while (d < 0 || d > (F * C) - M) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Error el numero de asientos a comprar debe ser mayor o igual a 0 y menor o igual que el número de asientos libres ("
                            + ((F * C) - M) + ")");
            d = TECLADO.nextInt();
        }

        M = M + d;

        if (d != 0) {
            System.out.println("Se pueden comprar " + d + " asientos.");
            if (M == (F * C)) {
                System.out.println("\nSe han ocupado todos los asientos.");
            } else {
                int countT=0;
                int i=0;
                // este bucle te lo cambio para que solo busque una fila que cumpla las condiciones
                for (i = 0; i < F && countT!=d; i++) { // aquí empiezo a tener el problema, por lo que el código estará mal
                    countT=0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < C && countT!=d; j++) {
                        if(asientos[i][j]==true)
                            countT++;
                    }
                }
                if(countT==d) {
                    System.out.println("Asientos disponibles en fila "+(i-1));
                }
                // imprimir al matriz con la misma tecnica que al principio 
                int dCopy=d;
                for (int z = 0; z < F; z++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
                        if (z==(i-1) && dCopy != 0 && asientos[z][j]) {
                            asientos[z][j] = false;
                            dCopy--;
                        }
                        System.out.print(asientos[z][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println(); // imprime un salto de linea
                }
                
                
            }
        }
    } while (d != 0 && M != (F * C));
```

También me gustaría decir que en mi respuesta me limito a arreglar y mejorar el código que planteas. Para solucionar este problema bien yo necesitaría reescribir el código de forma más clara y ordenada, y usando más estrategias que los bucles ( algún método privado, puede que algún salto incodicional etc... ) , pero entiendo que se trata de un problema académico , y que tienes que resolverlo con estas herramientas.

Saludos !!!!

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido de mucho!! Solo me queda una pregunta si no es molestia. ¿Por qué es necesario hacer una copia de M y d? ¿No se puede trabajar con los esos mismos?

Comment: Claro que no es molestia. La copia la hago porque ese dato lo editas en el proceso de marcar asientos en la matriz. Si te fijas lo que hago es , sabiendo que la fila en la que estoy tiene sitio, voy marcando los sitios como ocupados y restando valores a la copia hasta 0. Por supuesto podrías simplemente contar cuantos valores vas cambiando y luego comprobar que esa cuenta es igual a 'd', seria equivalente. Pero un dato que utilizas en varios lugares, es mejor no editarlo entre operaciones, da lugar a errores Runtime. En realidad seguramente me complicase la solución más de la cuenta :D